# How To Handle Array From Laravel Payment Gateway

Tags: laravel, payment-gateway

I just started learning laravel by building a site with a payment platform.
After a successful payment i get an array returned when i do  `dd($paymentDetails);`
[image: imgur link to image of the returned array]

I want to store the reference into the user database but sadly I don't know how to do that.
Here's my controller

```
public function handleGatewayCallback(Request $request)
{
    $paymentDetails = Paystack::getPaymentData();

    //dd($paymentDetails);

    if ($request) {
      $result = json_decode($request, true);
    }

    if (array_key_exists('data', $paymentDetails) && array_key_exists('status', $paymentDetails['data']) && ($paymentDetails['data']['status'] === 'success')) {
      echo "Transaction was successful";
        //Perform necessary action
    }else{
      echo "Transaction was unsuccessful";
    }

    // Now you have the payment details,
    // you can store the authorization_code in your DB to allow for recurrent subscriptions
    // you can then redirect or do whatever you want
}
```

I'll appreciate it if I am pointed to beginner friendly reading materials or tutorials that'll help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't store the reference directly on the `users` table, instead create an new table that set a relationship to `users` and stores the reference. This way a User -> HasMany -> Payments:

```
php artisan make:migration Payments --create=payments

// in your CreatePaymentsTable migration
$table->increments('id');
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
$table->unsignedInteger('reference');
...
// add more columns as needed
...
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

Create the `Payment` model and then add the relation in your `User` model:

```
public function payments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Payment::class);
}
```

Now you can store the reference in your controller as follows:

```
auth()->user()->payments()->create(['reference' => data_get($paymentDetails, 'data.reference')]);
```